# UIButton setImage behavior different in iOS6 sim vs iOS6 device?

Tags: uibutton, ios6

I set different images for my UIButtons, like so:

```
[testButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 416.0f, 64.0f, 64.0f)];
[testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

(The various images have different dimensions to which I re-size the UIButtons)

This works as expected in iPhone 6.0 simulator, but the images are not displayed on the buttons in an actual iOS 6.0 iPhone; the buttons are invisibly there with correct dimensions locations.

I want the same button behavior on the iPhone device; how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha ha!  *SIGH*  Of course, the filenames were mis-named.  Took 2 days to figure that out :(